# Interpreting MySQL (AWS RDS) CPU load and IOWAIT wrt threading model

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

This is a general question, not to solve a problem: Since MySQL uses one thread per connection. That means if you do IO, and it has to wait for it, the CPU that the thread runs on will be in IOWAIT. If you have as many MySQL threads as CPU threads, all CPUs will be in IOWAIT. But, that's not to say they can't do anything else. So as long as you still have IO scaling capacity, isn't the CPU use in panels like Amazon RDS misleading when you do many concurrent writes?

Part of this seems confirmed in Amazon RDS, where nowadays you see non-cpu load:

[image: RDS graph showing non-cpu load]

However, if you then go into Enhanced Monitoring, you things like this:

[image: enhanced monitoring]

Or in the overview:

[image: RDS overview]

In other words, would htop with 'detailed cpu stats' on show a bunch of **gray CPU bars** indicating that's not actual CPU power that is maxed out? Like this (example, NOT the actual MySQL server; it's not about the numbers shown):

[image: htop iowait]

Comment: "NOT the actual MySQL server" -- Please do not confuse the Question by including data directly related to the problem.

Comment: With the comment, I think it's clear enough that I'm talking about the gray bars. To me, an htop with gray bars speaks volumes and I think it does to many other sysops too. Perhaps I'm too biased towards that and others will look more at the numbers, but isn't it clear enough this way?

Answer (score 0):

- InnoDB has some background threads doing I/O.  So, *only some* I/O is being waited for.  I suggest that what is going on is too involved to make simplistic conclusions.
- Oracle 8.0 and Aurora have a *few* cases where multiple CPUs are deployed for a single connection.  It's too early to get excited about these rare cases of parallelism.
- Much of the possible I/O operations is avoided when `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is bigger than the dataset.
- 1K *connections* is not necessarily alarming.  100 Threads_running *is*.
- You have a small amount of Swap in use and nearly all of RAM in use.  This is worrisome.  Can you decrease `innodb_buffer_pool_size` slightly?  Or maybe lower some other memory settings?
- Assuming that htop is related,...  8 Cores, mostly busy -- It Sounds like some queries could use a better index and/or be reformulated.  Is the slowlog turned on?  Is `long_query_time` set no higher than `1`?
- If *previous* queries have made many index changes, I/O (reads and/or writes) could be involved in that.  Cf: "change buffering".  [Caveat:  I'm speaking for MySQL; RDS may work differently.]

Comment: No matter how big the buffer pool is, the write-ahead is always written. That's also what keeps thread_running busy, right? It's the number of threads not sleeping, so IOWAIT counts. As for the htop screenshot, that was just an example of any random server. Better remove your responses about that; it confuses. I edited my question to make it clear.

Comment: I know of some _read-ahead_, but it did not seam significant here.  What is involved in _write-ahead_?

Comment: I meant this: https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-new-lock-free-scalable-wal-design/. In my interpretation, that article indirectly suggests it's OK to have hundreds of threads running. Especially the picture at the bottom, which shows this write ahead log can now handle up to 512 connections (and more) writing.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that certain wait-for-mutex pauses are done via a CPU loop instead of interrupting to the system.  The former hangs onto the CPU (hopefully for only microseconds); the latter releases the CPU (but takes longer).

Answer (score 0):

I subjected a smaller instance to a similar load and amount of writing processes as what produced the graphs in the original post. Instead of 96 vCPUs, it has 16. This seems to confirm my theory:

[image: performance insight 16 cpu]

The green 'CPU' part of the bars seem mostly bound to the dotted line at 16, but the other part above the dotted line is just connections waiting for IO. This kind of CPU vs IO, and the two graphs 'CPU load' and 'non CPU-load' are only reported when you have performance insight turned on, so it's reported by MySQL.